# I belive Java is highly secured, But practically proved not. which is correct?

Tags: java, security, memory-leaks

I have a big question.. In many books of Java and SUN Microsystems is telling JAVA is highly Secured.  But one of my colleague is telling it is not secure.
Through constructor we can reach to object memory and can modify also..
He is practically did it.. But i believe that JAVA is highly secured..I Love JAVA..
Please tell me the What he said is correct?
Java is not secure?
How can i prove java is highly secured?

Comment: When downvote, Please tell me what's wrong? so that i will not do mistake next..

Comment: -1 because: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ."

Comment: The books are talking about the Java Security Model. Your colleague is talking about `this` leakage out of constructors. They aren't at all the same thing.

Comment: Its not clear what sort of security you are talking about or what he is talking about or whether you are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey He is  telling about java object is not secure.. I argued with him.. I posted here the discussion to get answer from Experts..

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary Its still not clear what you were arguing about. Can you give an example? Can you say what sort of security this example fails?

Comment: why not post the examples that he showed to you to prove that java is insecure?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey He is able to get java object memory reference and modifying,deleting.. so He is able to Hack the object,using constructor..

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary, I think if you need proof that why Java is more secured than C (for example) then one can provide that. But, how one can prove java is totaly secured or not secured. Because, in every security book the first line is no system is completely secure and that's why we have to belive on some core :).

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary, even if you can found many forums where people arguing about security features of their languages like C++ vs Java like here http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/55036-javas-being-more-secure-than-c.html.

Comment: You can modify the object you just created. This is the purpose of a constructor. Can you provide an example where you can modify or delete something you should not have access to? i.e. where you can defeat the security model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In many books of Java and SUN Microsystems is telling JAVA is highly Secured.

It is more secure from hacking from remote machines than without a VM.

> But one of my colleague is telling it is not secure.

Every form of security can be broken.

> Through constructor we can reach to object memory and can modify also.. He is practically did it..

That's what a constructor does. I don't see how that impacts security.

> But i believe that JAVA is highly secured..I Love JAVA..

Now get him to show you can do it to modify an object from another machine.

> Please tell me the What he said is correct? Java is not secure?

I don't see how the example demonstrate anything about the application's security.

> How can i prove java is highly secured?

You can't because it isn't. It just more secure than many of the alternatives (i.e. its a relative thing)

Comment: Through Constructor we can access object memory.. we can hack and do something.. It means what? Java object is secured ?

Comment: A constructors job is to access the object memory. It like saying; if I am alone in a secured room but I can harm myself, am I really secure? Java will not stop you from writing bugs or deliberately harming yourself if that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and clearly explained.. Thanks a lot...